# Why are my references not showed up?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I don't understand why my references are not showed up and why I have the following error message:

```
    Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                "Essai du 11 12 22"
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

This is my MWE:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[french]{babel}
    \usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
    \DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{french-apa}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{bib/\myname.bib}
    @Article{Blanchard-Laville2013a,
    author = {Blanchard-Laville, Claudine}, 
    title = {Accompagnement clinique et capacité négative}, 
    journal = {Cahiers de psychologie clinique}, 
    volume = {41}, 
    number = {2}, 
    pages = {63--80}, 
    year = {2013}, }
    \end{filecontents}
    \addbibresource{\myname.bib}
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    Some text \parencite{Blanchard-Laville2013a}.
    
    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Have you run `biber Essai du 11 12 22`?  Generally, you need to run `pdflatex`, then `biber`, then `pdflatex` at least twice more.

Comment: Yes, I did, but with no result. Can it be a biblatex issue?

Comment: Why does your sample code load `biblatex` twice? Your same code must be giving you an error related to the fact that you're not specifying a filename to store the contents of the `filecontents` environment. Your sample code is missing an `\addbibresource` statement.

Comment: I made the changes.

Comment: The instruction `\begin{filecontents}{bib/\myname.bib}` is almost surely a mistake. Please give ``\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bib/myname.bib}` a try.

Comment: The documents you have posted so far all will not work because they throw errors (that are most likely unrelated to your actual problem). Please try to compile the following valid MWE in a new, empty directory: https://gist.github.com/moewew/fcb1c36d1775414c760ea5927d1b199d. (Do not change anything about the document. You won't have to provide a suitable `.bib` file. The file `biblatex-examples.bib` is available on all systems where `biblatex` is installed correctly). This document needs to be compile with pdfLaTeX, Biber, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX. ....

Comment: ... If you ran Biber correctly, there should be a `.blg` file (on Windows systems this file might wrongly be classified as a "performance monitor file") that logs errors and warnings of the Biober run. Open this file (it is a simple text file) and paste its complete contents to your question.

Comment: @moewe: no problem with my blg.

Comment: why are you writing `bib/\myname.bib` but reading `\myname.bib` and where have you defined `\myname` ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a comment on the answer indicates the problem was a typo that was not included in the MWE.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why my references are not show[ing] up and why I have the following error message

- Please note that it's a warning message, not an error message.
- `biblatex` and `biber` are unable to create formatted bibliographic entries because your sample code is lacking an `\addbibresource` directive. E.g., if the bib file's name is `mybib.bib`, you need to run `\addbibresource{mybib.bib}`.
- You're not using the `filecontents` machinery correctly. In order for LaTeX to know which file it is supposed to write the contents of the `filecontents` environment to, you have to provide the filename. Hence, do change `\begin{filecontents}` to, say, `\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}`.

---

[image: scr]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{french-apa}
%\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex} % why this duplication?

%\usepackage{filecontents} % not needed
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib} 
@Article{Blanchard-Laville2013a,
author  = {Blanchard-Laville, Claudine}, 
title   = {Accompagnement clinique et capacité négative}, 
journal = {Cahiers de psychologie clinique}, 
volume  = {41}, 
number  = {2}, 
pages   = {63--80}, 
year    = {2013}, }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib} % <-- new

\begin{document}
\noindent
\parencite{Blanchard-Laville2013a}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you but it does not work for me. I always have the package biblatex warning above.

Comment: @domi - The code I posted does NOT generate a "please re-run biber" warning message -- unless, of course, one fails to run biber between latex runs. Please clarify what "it does not work for me" is supposed to mean.

Comment: This is the message i get: "LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 25.
[1
] (Essai du 11 12 22.aux)
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                "Essai du 11 12 22"
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards."

Comment: @domi - So we're talking about two rather different things: I am talking about the code I posted above, which does *not* generate any worrisome warning messages, while you appear to be talking about some other, presumably larger, document, of which I have no knowledge whatsoever. Sadly -- but maybe not surprisingly -- my mind-reading skills are utterly worthless. If you expect me to somehow know what's going on in your document, including how your document's biblatex setup differs from the one shown in the answer above, I apologize abjectly for letting you down rather badly.

Comment: @domi -- All I can surmise at present is that there are syntax or other errors in your document's `\addbibresource` directive or in the bib file itself.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is with Biblatex that I can't run. I don't have the same issue at all when I compile with Bibtex.

Comment: @domi - Since the sample code contains the instruction `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}`, it will do you no good at all to be running BibTeX. Instead, you should be running `biber`. You also wrote, "I don't have the same issue at all when I compile with Bibtex." Maybe not this particular warning message, but I'm willing to bet a substantial amount that you're getting real error messages, not just warning messages.

Comment: I found that I have a mistaken bib type entry. I wrote original year instead of originalyear or origdate. Now it works. Thanks for your kindness.